# fault-tolerant counters

Tags: erlang, riak

I would like to keep a set of counters in a fault-tolerant data store with the following properties:

- can communicate to it from erlang
- production ready
- fault tolerant out of the box (multi-server and no roll-your-own master-slave shenanigans)
- the number of counters is dynamic (let's say from 1k to 100k)

I am willing to trade C for AP. You may assume that the counters are only increasing. Things I've already considered:

**riak**

I assume one could try turning on allow_mult, and aggregating siblings at read time. This probably works great for sets but I'm unsure if it works for counters.

**riak_zab**

At the time of this writing it's not production ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some counters code in statebox in a branch that I've been prototyping:
https://github.com/mochi/statebox/tree/counters

This can be used in combination with Riak pretty easily.

It should work, but I haven't written an application with it yet so it's not on master yet. Doesn't fit your production ready goal, but nothing will (except maybe Mnesia, but there are other issues with that).

Comment: Fantastic. I started looking at statebox recently but I didn't notice the counters branch. Fortunately I don't need this tomorrow, so I'll just wait for it to get promoted to master. Thanks for creating that project - it looks really useful.

Comment: Just to note here, the counters branch has finally landed on master. We are not using it in production at this time, but it has 100% test coverage and some docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org). You will have use a port to run the zk c client in erlang, but it satisfies the rest of your requirements. A simple solution is to use Sequential nodes in zk, but there are other possible ways too.

Comment: Dont understand the reason for the downvote, but if someone could clarify, I'd be happy to edit the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure either. My limited understanding of zookeeper is that it's CP but not A because of the strict ordering. This makes it great for managing state that doesn't change often but potentially awful for counters.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the kind of counters use case you have ? Zookeeper does provide A - it will either respond successfully or refuse to respond. It operates in an ensemble model and as long as n/2+1 nodes are up, the ensemble will continue to operate.

Comment: I posed the question as a general problem which I encounter regularly: how do I keep critical stats like counters in a way that will tolerate a machine failure, but that any one statistic doesn't need to be the precise answer at that exact moment (AP but not C). For example, you could use this in ad serving to do ad pacing or budget tracking. When serving an ad you may not need the exact numbers but you need them NOW (not after a lock was released or agreement has been met). ZK also needs a high R/W ratio which I can't always guarantee.

Comment: Fair enough. If you dont have a high R/W ratio, zk may not be a good fit(although, I would first make sure it is valid for the particular use case). Not serving the precise answer is what ZK gives (as long as n/2+1 are up of course). You may get data that hasnt yet propagated to the node you are connected to, but you will get an answer. Dont mean to be evangelical about zk :), just making sure I understand.